# Consruct Member Class using Data computed in Composing Class

Tags: c++

I have a class `Itch` that is a member of the class `Scratch`.  I want to do some computations in the `Scratch` constructor and pass the result of these computations to instantiate the `Itch` object.  My best guess in doing this is below, but this returns garbage:

```
#include <iostream>

class Itch {
public:
  int N;
  Itch(int n) {N = n;}
};

class Scratch {
private:
  int N;
public:
  Itch it;
  Scratch(int n);
};

Scratch::Scratch(int n) : it(N)  // here is where I want to use new data
{
  // do some silly things
  int temp = 5;
  temp += n + 45;
  N = temp - 1;
}

int main() {
  int n = 1;
  Scratch sc(n);

  std::cout << sc.it.N << "\n";
}
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things in the initializer list happen before the things in the constructor code. Therefore, you cannot affect anything in the initializer list with the code in the constructor. You have a few options.

A reasonable approach would be to have an `Itch *` member rather than an `Itch`, and initialize it when it's ready, e.g.:

```
class Scratch {
  ...
  Itch *it;
  ...
};

Scratch::Scratch(int n) : it(NULL)
{
  // do some silly things
  int temp = 5;
  temp += n + 45;
  N = temp - 1;
  it = new Itch(N); // <- now you have enough info to instantiate an Itch
}
```

And you'll have to remember to clean up in the destructor unless you use an `auto_ptr`:

```
Scratch::~Scratch () {
  delete it;
}
```

Another reasonable approach would be to pass `n` to the `Itch` constructor and have it do the calculations there instead of in `Scratch`, perhaps even allowing `Itch` to determine `N`, e.g.:

```
class Itch {
private:
   int N;
public:
   Itch (int n);
   int getN () const { return N; }
}

Itch::Itch (int n) {
  // do some silly things
  int temp = 5;
  temp += n + 45;
  N = temp - 1;
}

Scratch::Scratch (int n) : it(n) {
  // you can either remove Scratch::N altogether, or I suppose do:
  N = it.getN();
  // ... do whatever makes sense, try not to have redundant data.
  // (also ask yourself if Scratch even *needs* to know N, or at
  // least if it can just use it.getN() everywhere instead of
  // keeping its own copy.)
}
```

Another approach, which IMO is a bit odd but it's still possible in some situations, is to have e.g. a static function (member or not) that computes `N` from `n`, which you can use in the initializer list, e.g.:

```
static int doSillyThings (int n) {
  int temp = 5;
  temp += n + 45;
  return temp - 1;
}

Scratch::Scratch(int n) : N(doSillyThings(n)), it(N)
{
}
```

Choose whichever leads to the cleanest, most maintainable and easy-to-read code. Personally I'd prefer the first, `Itch *` option, since it makes logical sense and is very clear: You do the calculations necessary to initialize the `Itch`, then you initialize it.

You should think about your code a bit. If the `Scratch`'s `N` is always equal to `it.N`, then do you *really* need both `N`s?

There are other options too (including restructuring your code completely so you don't *have* to have an `Itch` member of `Scratch`, or so that you don't have to have `it` depend on extra calculations done on the `Scratch`s constructor parameters but that really depends on the situation), but hopefully that inspires you a little.

---

The reason your code returns garbage, by the way, is because `N` *is* garbage at the point you pass it to the `Itch` constructor. It's uninitialized until you initialize it, and at the point where `it(N)` is you haven't initialized `N` yet.

Comment: Excellent!  I'll go with the first approach.  A question, though: must I still have `it(NULL)` in the initialization list?  As I recall, if a member object requires parameters for its constructor it must be constructed in an initialization list, so I suppose this is consistent with this requirement?

Comment: @bcf You don't have to have `it(NULL)` in the list. It just initializes the pointer to NULL instead of random garbage, but you're setting the pointer to something in the constructor anyways. I put it there because I like to make sure all members have predictable well-defined values at all times (I believe a pointer should be valid or be NULL at all times); in this case it means that at any point in the constructor code, you can tell if `it` has been set to a `new Itch()` or not yet by checking if its value is NULL. But really an `auto_ptr` handles that too and might be a better choice.

Comment: @bcf (Also keeping the pointer either NULL or valid helps with cleanup if exceptions are thrown - but again, `auto_ptr`). Note that `it(NULL)` has nothing to do with the `Itch` constructor!! That is *not* the `Itch` constructor. It just sets the pointer `it` to `NULL`, which you later set to a `new Itch(...)`.